# How to use SELECT in function to compare fields

Tags: sql, function

There are 3 tables: Event, Booking, and Booking_Day.

The idea is that one can book separate days of the event.

I would like to put a constraint on Booking_Day so that Day has to be within Date_Start and Date_End range of the corresponding Event. I decided to use a function that will do this

```
create table Event
(
  Event_ID   int identity
    constraint Event_pk
      primary key nonclustered,
  Date_Start date not null,
  Date_End   date
)

create table Booking
(
  Booking_ID int identity
    constraint Booking_pk
      primary key nonclustered,
  Event_ID   int not null
    constraint Booking_Event_Event_ID_fk
      references Event
)


create table Booking_Day
(
  Day        date not null,
  Booking_ID int  not null
    constraint Booking_Day_Booking_Booking_ID_fk
      references Booking,
  constraint Booking_Day_pk
    primary key nonclustered (Day, Booking_ID)
)
```

And the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_if_in_range (
    @Event_id int,
    @Day DATE
) RETURNS int
BEGIN
    declare @result TABLE  (Day DATE,Booking_ID INT,Event_ID INT,Date_start DATE, Data_end DATE)

    INSERT into @result

    SELECT Booking_Day.Day, Booking.Event_ID, Event.Date_Start, Event.Date_End

    FROM ((Booking_Day INNER JOIN Booking on Booking_Day.Booking_ID = B.Booking_ID )
    INNER JOIN Event on Event.Event_ID = Booking.Event_ID) WHERE Booking_Day.Day = @Day AND B.Event_ID = @Event_id

    return ((@Day >= @result.Date_start) AND (@Day <= @result.Data_end))

END
```

Because of the primary key constraint on Booking_day table, the above should return only one row.

When trying to add function do database I get “[[S0001][137] Must declare the scalar variable “@result".

How do I deal with it? Is my approach entirely wrong and I don’t need a table within the ​function for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you would be using a table variable for this.  You cannot just refer to a table unless you specify a `FROM` clause -- you are confusing table variables and scalar variables.

But why bother with variables at all?

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM Booking_Day bd INNER JOIN
                 Booking b
                 ON bd.Booking_ID = B.Booking_ID INNER JOIN
                 Event e
                 ON e.Event_ID = b.Event_ID
           WHERE b.Day = @Day AND
                 b.Event_ID = @Event_id AND
                 @Day >= e.Date_Start AND
                 @Day <= e.Data_end
          )
        )
BEGIN
    return 1
END;
return 0
```